# Crashing threads with *(int*)NULL = 1; problematic?

Tags: c, clang, assert, volatile, gcc-warning

I found this in a multi-threaded c application. The authors commented that it's used to make a thread crash in a custom assert function. GCC is fine with it, but clang issues the following warning:

```
note: consider using __builtin_trap() or qualifying pointer with 'volatile'
```

and also issues one of those, for each usage of the assert function:

```
warning: indirection of non-volatile null pointer will be deleted, not trap
```

What is going on here? Is __builtin_trap specific to clang? Should I use it?

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as making a thread crash; any crash crashes the whole program...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Writing to `NULL` address is not guaranteed to crash your program reliably, so [GCC introduced `__builtin_trap`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for that.

It looks like clang decided to go further, and eliminate such writes altogether, almost forcing you into using `__builtin_trap`. Their other option of casting `NULL` to `volatile` pointer does not look attractive compared to `__builtin_trap`, because it's "merely" an undefined behavior.

Comment: That said, just adding that `volatile` might be the easiest way out if you are touching code compiled also by other compilers without support for GCC extensions.

Comment: In my current, clang-based configuration, `__builtin_trap()` merely calls `abort()` which makes it pointless. If I want to call `abort()` I can just call `abort()`. `volatile` does the job for now.

The GCC reference above says: "GCC implements this function by using a target-dependent mechanism (such as intentionally executing an illegal instruction) or by calling abort. The mechanism used may vary from release to release so you should not rely on any particular implementation."