# What does this mean?: *(int32 *) 0 = 0;

Tags: c

In the following piece of code, what does `*(int32 *) 0 = 0;` mean?

```
void
function (void)
{
  ...

  for (;;)
     *(int32 *) 0 = 0;     /* What does this line do? */
}
```

A few notes:

- The code seems to not be reachable, as there is an exit statement before that particular piece of code.
- `int32` is `typedef`'ed but you shouldn't care too much about it.
- This piece of code is from a language's runtime in a compiler, for anyone interested.

Comment: It's an infinite loop storing 4 bytes of zero into locations 0-3. It looks like an intentional abort or intentional hang.

Comment: @Habib yes ofcourse I know that `for (;;)` is an infinite loop. The piece below that is the one I don't understand. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @Curtis I don't think it's a bad thing. This is written by experienced compiler engineers, and it must be there for a reason. Abnormal execution in case something something goes wrong seems like a plausible reason, given the answers so far.

Comment: It means Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The code is doing the following:

```
   for (;;) // while(true)
     *(int32 *) 0 = 0; // Treat 0 as an address, de-reference the 0 address and try and store 0 into it.
```

This should segfault, null pointer de-reference.

**EDIT**

Compiled and ran for further information:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){
  *(int32_t *) 0 = 0;
  printf("done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

`gcc -g null.c; ./a.out`

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004004cd in main () at null.c:7
7         *(int32_t *) 0 = 0;
```

Comment: @Hrishi: On any reasonable system (except perhaps for some very small embedded platforms), the fault will only affect that one program.

Comment: @KeithThompson I thought the operating system would store a pointer table to its routines in the lower addresses in memory? is that not true anymore in modern operating systems?

Comment: @Hrishi: I have no idea -- but on any modern multi-processing OS (Unix, Linux, Windows, ...), an unprivileged program cannot corrupt OS-level data structures (unless there's a bug on the OS, but such a bug is unlikely to be triggered by such trivial code). Typically each process has its own virtual address space; address 0 for your process, if it exists, has nothing to do with address 0 for the kernel or for any other process.

Comment: @Hrishi: Typically due to way bootloaders are working the OS will be loaded into 'low' physical memory address space. Also there used to be a case that low physical memory was valuable for DRM. However most OSes will run from within virtual memory and on x86 it will occupy highier quarter (32 bit) or higher half (64 bit). In any case the physical space and virtual space are only loosely connected. This might not be the case for some embedded platforms which sometimes don't have virtual memory (and sometimes even standard compliant C compiler).

Comment: @Hrishi You may be interested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18413368/486504), where I touch on that issue. It started off as a comment, but then (also as it grew longer than the comment box) I realized it could add some value as an answer.

Comment: @Hrishi Every modern PC operating system (and hardware) uses memory protection to prevent programs from writing outside their own address space, or into the OS's internal structures. I think the last significant OSes to lack this feature were MacOS 9 and Windows 95.  Even the tiny embedded-realtime OSes QNX and VxWorks have memory protection.

Comment: The OP doesn't say where this code was from.  There was a good 20 years of C coding between the creation of C and the last systems that didn't use protected memory.  (I personally last used such a system in 1999, an embedded system using the Z80.)

Answer (score 27):

Since the OP states the code was written by experienced compiler engineers, it is possible this is the intent of the code:

- `*(int32 *) 0 = 0;` is recognized by this specific C implementation as code that causes behavior not defined by the C standard and known to this implementation to be illegal.
- The `for (;;)` additionally indicates that this code is never exited.
- The compiler engineers know that the optimizer will recognize this code and deduce that it may be “optimized away”, because any program that reaches this code is permitted to have any behavior, so the optimizer may choose to give it the behavior as if the code is never reached.<sup>1</sup>

This sort of reasoning is possible **only** if you have specific knowledge of the internal operation of a C implementation. It is the sort of thing a compiler engineer **might** include in special headers for a C implementation, perhaps to mark that certain code (such as code after an `abort` call) is never reached. It should never be used in normal programming.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, consider this code:

```
if (a)
    for (;;)
        *(int 32 *) 0 = 0;
else
    foo();
```

The compiler can recognize that the then-clause is permitted to have any behavior. Therefore, the compiler is free to choose what behavior it has. For simplicity, it chooses it to have the same behavior as `foo();`. Then the code becomes:

```
if (a)
    foo();
else
    foo();
```

and can be further simplified to:

```
foo();
```

Answer (score 21):

In fact that this code seg-faulting doesn't explain why it's exists =)

I think that's from runtime of some MCU.. and reason it is there because if program execution will get to this point such instruction will either initiate software reset for an MCU, so program will be restarted (which is common practice in embedded development) OR if MCU configured with hardware watchdog, force MCU restart because of hardware watchdog and never ending loop.

Main goal of such constructions to invoke an interrupt which can be handled either by OS or by hardware for initiate certain actions.

Knowing that its x86 it will depend on a CPU mode... in Real Mode nothing will really happened instantly if there is no watchdog, at address 0 there is an address of 'divide by 0' handler, so if it's some old MS-DOS or embedded x86 runtime it will change an address of the 'Divide by 0' handler to 0, so as soon as it happens and this interrupt is not masked CPU will jump to location 0:0 and probably will just restart because of illegal instruction.. if it's protected or VM x86 code then it's a way to notify OS or any other supervisor that there is a problem in runtime and software should be 'killed' externally.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation dude! However this is x86-targeted code and never seems to be executed. There is an `exit(0)` before that particular piece of code, and I believe it's there to abort in case there is something wrong with `exit` itself.

Answer (score 6):

`for(;;)` is equivalent to `while(1)`,

`*(int32 *) 0 = 0;`writes 0 to a dereferenced null pointer, which is expected to cause a crash, but actually won't at all times on certain compilers: [Crashing threads with *(int*)NULL = 1; problematic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10153246)

Answer (score 3):

It's an infinite loop of undefined behavior (dereferencing a null pointer). It's likely to crash with a segfault on *n*x or Access Violation on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's comment is pretty well correct: it's storing the VALUE zero at the ADDRESS 0.

Which will be a crash on most machines.

Answer (score 3):

The original [IBM PC stored the interrupt vector table in the lowest 1 KiB of memory](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#Overview). Hence actually writing a 32-bit value to the address 0 on such an architecture would overwrite the address for `INT 00h`. [INT 00h looks unused in the PC.](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-00.htm)

On basically anything modern (meaning in x86/x86-64 parlace anything running in *protected* or *long* mode), it will trigger a segmentation fault unless you are in ring 0 (kernel mode) because you are stepping outside of your process' allowed address dereference range.

As the dereference is undefined behavior (as already stated), a segmentation fault is a perfectly acceptable way to handle that situation. If you know that on the target architecture a zero address dereference causes a segmentation fault, it's seems to be a pretty sure way to get the application to crash. If `exit()` returns, that's probably what you want to do, since something just went horribly wrong. That the code is from a particular compiler's runtime means whoever wrote it can take advantage of knowledge of the internal workings of the compiler and runtime, as well as tailor it to the specific target architecture's behavior.

Comment: 00h was the divide by zero interrupt on DOS.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call) I doubt that's what's going on here, though.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the compiler doesn't know `exit()` doesn't return, but it does know this construct does not return.